# bindfs in fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, fuse

I am struggling to get this to work properly.

This works in terminal

```
sudo bindfs -u dave /media/dave/Documentary2Lin/RAIDMain/Documentary2 ~/shares/Documentary2
```

How do I get this to work in fstab?

I've tried

```
/media/dave/Documentary2Lin/RAIDMain/Documentary2 ~/shares/Documentary2 fuse.bindfs force-user=dave perms=a=rX 0 0
```

It gives an error in fstab

Comment: `~/shares/Documentary2` shouldn't be relative path, all paths in fstab should be absolute (full) paths.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this by using the Upstart system to run all of my bindfs scripts after the file system has loaded.

Create a file:

```
/etc/init/mount-bindfs.conf
```

With contents like:

```
description "Remount directories with different permissions"

start on stopped mountall 

script
  bindfs -o force-user=dave perms=a=rX /media/dave/Documentary2Lin/RAIDMain/Documentary2 /home/dave/shares/Documentary2
end script
```

According to the [extensive and detailed how-to on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1460472) the correct syntax is something like this:

```
bindfs#/media/dave/Documentary2Lin/RAIDMain/Documentary2 /home/dave/shares/Documentary2 fuse force-user=dave perms=a=rX 0 0
```

But this does not work unless the shared directory is in the root partition.